# How to trigger keyboard click event on a text field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keycode

I want to click enter instead of submit button and I want jquery to do the exact same task as if I were clicking the submit button.

This is what I have but its not working

the jquery

```
$("#search-friend-text").keypress(function(e){ // start enter click

    switch(e){

        case 13: 
        $.post("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/search_friend'); ?>", 
        $("#add-friend-search").serialize(),
        function(data){
           $("#insert-activity").html(data);
        });

    $("#add-friend-search").slideUp("slow",function(){});
    break;

    }

}); // end enter click
```

the Html (form)

```
<form method="post" action="" name="searchFriendForm" id="add-friend-search">
<input type="text" id="search-friend-text" name="searchFriendText">
<input type="button" class="small green button" id="add-friend-button" />


</form>
```

Comment: are you able to say where the error occur ? is the post request done ? firebug can tell you that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will solve it

```
switch(e.keyCode)
```

Since `e` is the event handler

Answer (score 4):

use e.keyCode :

```
switch(e.keyCode) {
. ..
```

Comment: +1 and just sharing... either `e.keyCode` or `e.which` would work here. I use this page (http://www.din.or.jp/~hagi3/JavaScript/JSTips/Mozilla/Samples/KeyEvent.htm) to check myself when I can't remember.

Answer (score 2):

First off as Vlad has pointed out, you need to provide the switch with the number and not the event object. Secondly, if you are only going to look for one number, there isn't a need to use the switch/case. Try this:

```
$("#search-friend-text").keypress(function(e) { // start enter click
    if (e.which === 13) {
        $.post("<?php echo site_url('userProfile/search_friend'); ?>", $("#add-friend-search").serialize(), function(data) {
            $("#insert-activity").html(data);
        });
        $("#add-friend-search").slideUp("slow", function() {});
    }
}); // end enter click
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the submit event.

```
$('#search-friend-text').submit(function() {
    // Ajax stuff...
});
```

Comment: No, you've got a fair point. Any code that happens on submit should kept in as a submit event listener, and artificially triggered if an explicit submit isn't performed.

Answer (score 0):

The event you receive in your keypress is an event object so i'm not sure your switch/case statement would work anyway! and you can trigger a keypress event for an item by simply invoking $("target").keypress( e ) -- where e is an event you need to build that has the character keycode in it ( you will have to set it in evet.which )

Answer (score 0):

Well you can take a look at this function in jQuery: [triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/)

But really, it might be better to move your click event code into a separate function which you can call from the click event and from the keypress event.